# How can I run a job in Jenkins n-times?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, groovy

Is it possible in Jenkins to create a job, that will run n-times?

I would like to write a script in configuration (windows batch command / groovy) which allows me to do it. In this script, I would like to have an array with parameters and then run this job with each parameter in the cycle. It should look like that:

```
paramArray [] = ["a","b","c"];
for(int i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i++)
{
    //Here I want to run this job with each parameter
    job.run(paramArray[i]);
}
```

Please, help me with that issue.

Comment: Are you writing this code (for loop with parameters) in a Jenkinsfile? Do you need to collect parameters at run time from user?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing this code (loop with parametrs) in Jenkinsfile. 
Yes, I need to collect parametrs from user (parametrized job)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer!

We need to create 2 pipelines in Jenkins: downstream and upstream jobs.

**1. The downstream job is parameterized and take 1 string parameter in 'General' section**
[image]

**Then, it just prints the choosing parameter in 'Pipeline' section:**
[image]

**Here is the result of this downstream job:** 
[image]

**2. The upstream job has an array with all possible parameters for a downstream job. 
   And in the loop, it runs a downstream job with each parameter from an array.** 
[image]

**In the result, an upstream job will run a downstream job 3 times with each parameter.**

:)

Comment: Good job. Did tou try to read list from a jenkins parameter (LETTER), and not to define directly in a pipeline script?

Comment: For example: def arr = LETTER.split(',') as String[]

println "Array is: ${arr}"

for (item in arr) { ... }

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't run Jenkins job according to your above code. But you can configure the cronjob in Jenkins using “Build periodically” for run Jenkins job periodically.

go to **Jenkins job** > **Configure** > **tick Build periodically in build Triggers**
and put cronjob syntax like below image and Save.

[image]

This job runs every 15 minutes. and also you can set a specific time in the schedule.

Comment: thank you for the answer.
But how can it help me to run my job with a different parameter for each run?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the example from https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/ in "Handling parameters" section: With a Jenkinsfile like this (example here copied from that doc), you can launch "Build with parameters" and give params. Since you want multiple params, you can delimit them with , or ; or something else based on your data. You just need to parse the input params to get the values using the delimiter you chose.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'Greeting', defaultValue: 'Hello', description: 'How should I greet the world?')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo "${params.Greeting} World!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please write in this example how can I pass an array with parameters?